# Call Vehicle Routing Problem Service via REST - Problem with "time" attributes?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, web-service, linux, arcgis-rest-api

I am trying to get a Vehicle Routing Problem to work as a geoprocessing service on one of our servers.

If I call the geoprocessing service via REST url and submit depots, orders and routes WITHOUT time information, output stops are returned. As soon as I also submit time information (TimeWindowStart1 etc.), no output stops are returned.

I have tried different time formats: "10:00:00", "10:00 AM", Unix Timestamp (with and without the "), but no success.

Before I publish the service, the VRP works on my ArcGIS Desktop with times.

Our ArcGIS Server configuration: ArcGIS Server 10.1.1 with Security Patch 1, System: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.3, 64 bit

Here's one of the REST commands that I tried. Can anyone spot a mistake?

```
http://arcgisserver01.cloud.alta4.com:6080/arcgis/rest/services/koop_uni_fh_trier/TrierApp/GPServer/SolveVRP/submitJob?
orders={
 "displayFieldName": "POIs",
 "geometryType": "esriGeometryPoint",
 "spatialReference": {
  "wkid": 3857,
  "latestWkid": 3857
 },
 "features":[
 {
    "attributes":{
        "Name":"POI1", 
        "TimeWindowStart1": 1367820000,
        "TimeWindowEnd1": 1367848800,
        "MaxViolationTime1":0,
        "ServiceTime":10
    },
    "geometry":{"x":739116,"y":6404262.603}
 },
 {
    "attributes":{
        "Name":"POI2",
        "TimeWindowStart1": 1367820000,
        "TimeWindowEnd1": 1367848800,
        "MaxViolationTime1":0,
        "ServiceTime":10
    },
    "geometry":{"x":739216,"y":6404262.603}
 }
 ]
}
&routes={
 "displayFieldName": "Route",
 "features": [
 {
    "attributes":{
        "Name":"myRoute", 
        "StartDepotName":"myStartPoint", 
        "EndDepotName":"myEndPoint",
        "EarliestStartTime": 1367820000,
        "LatestStartTime": 1367820000,
        "MaxOrderCount": 30
    }
 }
 ],
 "exceededTransferLimit": false
}
&depots={
 "displayFieldName": "Start- and Endpoint",
 "geometryType": "esriGeometryPoint",
 "spatialReference": {
  "wkid": 3857,
  "latestWkid": 3857
 },
 "features": [
 {
    "attributes":{
        "Name":"myStartPoint"
    },
    "geometry":{"x":739612,"y":6404755}
 },
  {
    "attributes":{
        "Name":"myEndPoint"
    },
    "geometry":{"x":739612,"y":6404755}
 }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Unless you have records with timestamps between `Sat Jan 17 1970 05:57:00 GMT+1000 (EST)` and `Sat Jan 17 1970 05:57:28 GMT+1000 (EST)`, I wouldn't expect that you would get any data back.  Try the bounds of `(-8640000000000000, 8640000000000000)` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I have tried the values that you have mentioned, but I get the same result as before. I have tried: EarliestStarttime and TimeWindowStart1 with -8640000000000000 and LatestStartTime and TimeWindowEnd1 with 8640000000000000.

Comment: I wouldn't know what to say then, this problem seems fairly localized to your situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with the rest interface it doesn't understand time in human form.  It has to be in milliseconds, there's more information in the help section in your rest catalog, but specifically:

time    Description: The time instant or the time extent to query.

Time instant

Syntax: time=
Example: time=1199145600000 (1 Jan 2008 00:00:00 GMT)

Time extent

Syntax: time=, 
Example: time=1199145600000, 1230768000000 (1 Jan 2008 00:00:00 GMT to 1 Jan 2009 00:00:00 GMT) 
A null value specified for start time or end time will represent infinity for start or end time respectively.

Comment: The technical word for this is miliseconds in the Unix Epoch.